# how to get specific values from string?

Tags: javascript

I am getting a variable which value always follows this format:

```
"<div>
    &nbsp;</div>
<div>
    <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;"><span>VALUE 1</span></span></div>
<div>
    <strong><span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;">VALUE 2</span></strong></div>
<div>
    <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;"> </span>VALUE 3</div>
"
```

How can I get **VALUE 1**, **VALUE 2** and **VALUE 3** using JavaScript (not jQuery or other libs)?

NB:

in Console, I get those values (I call them **b**)
`typeof(b)` returns `string`

Comment: You can get them by parsing the string as HTML and using DOM routines.

Comment: Are you sure about the markup you shared ?

Comment: your format is very irregular, the span are unordered, You should use the same format to display the values `<span>VALUE 1</span> .. <span>VALUE 2</span> .. <span>VALUE 3</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

`innerHTML` the string to a `temp` element and use `DOM-api` to manipulate data.

Use *`'span[style]'`* selector to get only those span elements having `style` attribute.

```js
var str = '<div>\
  &nbsp;</div>\
<div>\
  <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;"><span>VALUE 1</span></span>\
</div>\
<div>\
  <strong><span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;">VALUE 2</span></strong></div>\
<div>\
  <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;">VALUE 3</span></div>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;
var spanElems = div.querySelectorAll('span[style]');
var spans = [].map.call(spanElems, function(el) {
  return el.textContent.trim();
}).filter(Boolean);
console.log(spans);
```

Comment: Your response is `[ "VALUE 1", "VALUE 1", "VALUE 2"]` should be `[ "VALUE 1", "VALUE 2", "VALUE 3"]`

Answer (score 3):

The most simplest way using `jQuery`.

```js
var a = '<div>\
    &nbsp;</div>\
<div>\
    <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;"><span>VALUE 1</span></span></div>\
<div>\
    <strong><span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;">VALUE 2</span></strong></div>\
<div>\
    <span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;">au </span>VALUE 3</div>'

var HTML = $.parseHTML(a)
var val1 = $(HTML[1]).find('span span').text()
var val2 = $(HTML[2]).find('span').text()
$(HTML[3]).find('span').remove()
var val3 = $(HTML[3]).text()
console.log(val1, val2, val3)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer is valid, but the tag is only `javascript`

Comment: And do not edit the question to include the `jquery` tag, since the question itself *specifically states* the OP does **not want jQuery**.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the string as a variable, and then use `htmlString.match(/VALUE \d+/gmi)`

Comment: thank you , but VALUE is not the real value of VALUE.

Comment: If all of the `VALUE`s were each in their own span tag, this would be simple. Without them, the best solution I can come up with is regex. What is the real value here? What distinguishes it from the rest of the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

If the input is a valid HTML string you could parse with this trick (**not jQuery or other libs**):

```js
var your_string = `<div>&nbsp;</div><div><span style="font family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;"><span>VALUE 1</span>fgfgfg</span></div><div><strong><span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;">VALUE 2</span></strong></div><div><span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif;">  </span>VALUE 3</div>`

var obj_evaluator = document.createElement("div");
obj_evaluator.innerHTML = your_string;
// get the list of div 
var list_div = obj_evaluator.getElementsByTagName('div');
var value1 = (list_div[1].firstChild.firstChild.textContent);  //value 1
var value2 = (list_div[2].firstChild.firstChild.textContent);  //value 2
var value3 = (list_div[3].lastChild.textContent);  //value 3
// create an array
var result = [value1,value2,value3]
// print result
console.log(result);
```

**Old answer** (wrong because of the VALUE 3,but **if all the VALUE are inside the 'span'**  then this is the right answer! ):

```
var obj_evaluator = document.createElement("div");
obj_evaluator.innerHTML = your_string;
// debug row
console.log(obj_evaluator);
var list_span = obj_evaluator.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0; i < list_span.length; i++) {
    console.log(list_span[i].innerHTML);
    // here you can print other info of the node
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this prints out `VALUE 3`, since `VALUE 3` is not in a `<span>` tag.